# How to delete a specific element that was added to a frame in a linked list with a button?

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jbutton

I am trying to find out the code for how to delete a selected "player" and "score". I have the form created with the buttons set up. The add player button, adds the player + their score, and I have created a button called `btnRemove` and I would like it to delete a selected player from my raw data. Here is my code.

```
private void btnAddPlayerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // read artist and title and add to the list
    String artist = txtName.getText();
    String title = txtScore.getText();

    //add it to the list
    playerLib.add(artist, title);

    //display our data in the raw list - debugging/testing only
    lstRaw.add(artist + ", " + title);
}                                            

private void btnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    System.exit(0);
}                                       

private void btnRemoveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
//code to delete player
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this code is to short to give a good answer. Please provide a SSCCE ( http://sscce.org ) so that all components involved are visible.

Comment: Agree with @TimothyTruckle on posting an SSCCE or [mcve]. The `LinkedList` interface defines no method for adding two `String` arguments in the `add` method, so it's hard to even tell which form of linked list is being used here.

Comment: If the question does not include sufficient information (like what is 'playLib' ) the only answer I can provide, similarly, is: use  `playerLib.remove(artist, title);`